# Allow only https for multiple domains in Nginx

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I want to point `example.com` to `localhost:3000` and `api.example.com` to `localhost:3010`. Following [this](https://code.lengstorf.com/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab) tutorial I managed to get it to work but it's not very secure. Do you guys have an idea how to restrict it to https only? If I go to http://example.com I get a "Not Secure" by the URL in Chrome.

Here's my default sites Nginx config (the one in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
server {
        # HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        # Enable HTTP/2
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
}
```

Made a config file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
    # Use SSL certificates from Letsencrypt
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include SSL config from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

}

Made another config file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/api.example.com.conf

```
 server {
            server_name example.com;

            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

            include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

            location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:3010/;
                    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_redirect off;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you detail the current behavior of your nginx server ?

Comment: Test the configuration using `nginx -T`. You seem to have two server blocks with a missing `server_name` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that your server_name directive is identical in both files, even though you imply that you want your server_name in api.example.com.conf to be api.example.com.

Also, I think you have to specify the ports within the same server blocks as the server_name directive. Maybe try something like below. Since your default conf file does not specify a server_name, I don't think it'll be referenced at all.

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    # Use SSL certificates from Letsencrypt
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include SSL config from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/api.example.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    return 301 https://api.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3010/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```